# Django how do you reverse query to set image field upload_to path

Tags: django, python-2.7

```
def uploadPath(instance,filename):
    return ''.join([instance.uploadPath(), filename])
class abstractClass(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=uploadPath, default='default.png')
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
class A(abstractClass):
    manager = CharField(max_length=30, default='')
    uploadPath = 'managerPhoto/'
    def __str__:
        return self.manager
class B(abstractClass):
    worker = CharField(max_length=30, default='')
    uploadPath = 'workerPhoto/'
    def __str__:
        return self.worker
```

Okay guys this is just an example code I wrote up so don't shoot me if it doesn't work. In this example both class A and B inherit an image field and we have a callable uploadPath that will check the value of uploadPath on the corresponding model and assign it for this model instance but, I would like to set the upload path starting point as the 'managers' name so say we have Manager = 'Tim' we have a folder called Tim with his image in there but I would like to have class B generate its new folder within 'Tim' folder for all the workers that work for him. How do I go about doing this or possibly reverse query?

one option I tried working with was during the call to uploadPath(instance,filename) ''.join([instance.**str**(),'/',instance.uploadPath,filename])

I inserted instance.**str**() to get the instance returned name but, this is model specific.....

Comment: you either need to pass the managers name when you upload a worker photo, or if you have a model that associates a manager with a worker, then you can use that in your `uploadPath` function

Comment: Okay thank you that got me on the right track at this point I tossed in a foreign key to Class A for Class B and was able to grab the managers name through a defined function.